Since gluons are confined, would massive gluons behave similarly to massless gluons?
Due to confinement, the strong interaction effectively only acts at short range. So if the gluons had some small non-zero mass (say they acquired it from a Higgs mechanism with a new "strong-Higgs" field, with a small VEV but a large mass for the "strong-Higgs" boson), would we notice the difference? Would such a theory behave qualitatively similarly to standard QCD?

This is a needless complication to a theory that works well as is. What would be the point?
